# Как получить никнейм пользователя telegram зная его id Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Как получить никнейм пользователя telegram зная его id на python? А если точнее есть ли вообще подобный функционал в библиотеках?

Comment: [How to obtain username from UserID in Telegram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691233/how-to-obtain-username-from-userid-in-telegram). Попробуйте в следующий раз использовать Google или поиск в Stack Overflow (в том числе и русский).